# Deploy a project in local machine server using Docker

Tags: docker, yii, yii2, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello I am studying Docker for our new version of our ERP System. We have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server then in my production I have Windows 7 OS.
I dont have any idea how to deploy the system. Our consultant gave me an idea to deploy it using Docker. I don't know what is the configuration of Docker in local deployment. the project is developed using YII 2.0

Can you help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are asking if it is possible to develop your system in PHP in Ubuntu and then deploy in Windows 7 using docker. Yes it is possible. Although in Windows 7 for production, well it is not the right OS for production. And docker will run there using Docker Toolbox.

I recommend you go to official docker page for information.

The docker way ensure you if the thing works in your dev box it will work in another system with minor adjustments.

Regards